# Unity: how to position items into a Scroll View?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to add items (prefab) into a Scroll View but either if I simply add items without set positions and trying to setting position it not work.

Case 1: without setting position

Result: All items overlapping

Case 2: forcing positions (like commented row code below)

Result: Items not overlapped but X position take the same value (that not is 0)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
 {
        GameObject newObj= Instantiate(MyRowPrefab);
        newObj.transform.SetParent(ScrollViewObject.transform, false);
        //newObj.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, (-1 * ((i * rowHeight))), 0);
        // If i decomment this line, X isn't set to zero... why ?
  }
```

Comment: Did you mean to use anchoredPosition?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.. I simply want to add 1,2..n items one below the previous...

Comment: You mean like a [VerticalLayoutGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html)?

Comment: Oh yes.. you're right, as ever ! Thank you

Comment: Please take time to read the documents and review introductory UI tutorials when you have questions about core layout functionality of an engine.

Comment: Just a heads up you'll probably want a vertical layout group on the Content of your scroll view, and then a content size fitter with min height. Your elements in the layout group should have a layout element on them with their min height set. LayoutGroups tend to never work how you picture them to, but that's the setup that normally works for me. You can change the pivot and anchors to control how the content scales up/down.

Comment: @gjh33 that looks to me like it would make a good answer.